# Java change cursor

Tags: java, swing, cursor

is there any way to change the cursor in Java at all, not just for one JComponent?

I need this because I want the cursor to change, when your mouse leaves the JFrame, so there is no JComponent in the background.

Thanks for your help!

esanits

Answer (score 2):

Setting [cursor on your JFrame](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFramesetCursorCursorc.htm) or top level window should do the trick

Comment: I want to change the cursor while dragging a JComponent out of my JFrame. This doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the system cursor (i.e. when the cursor is outside your application), this is the responsibility of your system. I don't think you can change the system's settings from Java in a platform-independent way.